# Texture bake procedural material fire not working?

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-baking, shader-nodes, procedural

I want to texture bake [my fire](https://ibb.co/X5MXtBP), using [this texture bake procedural material](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AioskAgcU2U), but ended up with a black texture instead. How do I texture bake my fire like in this tutorial?

[My Blender fire file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/6eK8Zasd)